# How to write/read data into SRAM of STM32L476RG via Arduino ide

Tags: arduino, stm32, arduino-ide

i have an issue into writing and then reading the data collected by a temperature & humidity sensor into the SRAM of my uC.
Im working,in ARDUINO IDE, on an STM32L476RG and i need to save some data (integer number) into the SRAM of the micro. The purpose is to store variuos type of data untill we want to send a package of information throught bluetooth so i need to store and read this data.
The problem is that i can't find any documentations of this process made in arduino.
Any suggestions?

P.S im using the expansion board X-NUCLEO-IKS01A1 to collect the data from the HTS221 sensor

[This is the memory mapping of the micro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd02Z.png)

i've found some documentation wrote in ST-CUBE ide but it doesn't match my needs.
i would be so gratefull if you guys could give me some help into writing in the memory.

Comment: all variables are in the SRAM. so create an array and write values into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Any declared not `const` variable is placed into the SRAM memory of this micro.

```
unsigned int temperature = read_temperature();
```

It will define a variable `temperature`, having type of `unsigned int`, located in the SRAM memory and initialized with the return value of the method `read_temperature`.

You do not need to do anything special.

> P.S im using the expansion board X-NUCLEO-IKS01A1 to collect the data
> from the HTS221 sensor
>
> This is the memory mapping of the micro

I would suggest starting from the basic C++ book, not from the uC technical documentation. Generally to program microcontrollers in Arduino, you need to learn at least some basics of  C++ first.